# Reading words from file with fscanf

Tags: c

I have a file .txt with the following encoding:

```
Alpha-Beta-Gamma-Delta-Epsilon
Zeta-Eta-Theta-Iota-Kappa-Lamda-Mi
Ni-Ksi-Pi-Ro-Sigma
```

I want to read those words and store them in an array.
I read those words with `fscanf(fp, "%[^-]", word)`

But when I put `fscanf` inside a while, it keeps reading the same word. If I put it inside the while statement it doesn't repeat.

**The point is to read every word separately from Alpha to Sigma**

I provide you a minimal-verifiable code with the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char *word = (char*)malloc(40);
    int count = 0;
    char* Words[30]; //max 30
    fp = fopen("MyWords.txt","r"); //read only
    int r = 1;
    while(1){
        if(fscanf(fp, "%[^-]", word) == EOF) break;
        printf("%s",word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I don't want to modify the file. Also how should I handle with the `\n` characheter

Comment: Code never reads a `'-'`, so scanning is stuck on that.  `'-'` remains in `fp`.

Comment: `station`? And shouldn't the test from `fscanf` be `==1`?

Comment: fixed that,sorry

Comment: Please post your actual [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, which you compiled, ran, and verified. It seems as if you are guessing.

Comment: `if(fscanf(fp, "%[^-]", word) == EOF) break;`  --> what should code do if `fscanf()` returned 0?

Comment: Your "minimal verifiable" code doesn't compile. Please fix! Also, note that `sizeof(word)` doesn't do what you want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit input with a width specifier of 39, 1 less than the 40 bytes available to `word` as `fscanf()` will append a *null character*.  Continue reading as long as successful in that `fscanf()` returned 1.  Consume the following delimiter be it a `'-'` or `'\n'`,

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%39[^-\n]", word) == 1) {
    printf("<%s>\n",word);
    fscanf(fp, "%*[-\n]"); // consume delimiter, no need to save.
}
```

Note: Use `[^-\n]` and not `[^\n-]` as placing the `-` later looks like the beginning of an incomplete *scan-set* range.

Comment: Is there any way to know whether `fscanf` delimits `\n` ? To know when the line have changed

Comment: @Theo.Fanis To know when the line have changed, code could use `char delimit[2]; fscanf(fp, "%1[-\n]", delimit);` and test `delimit[0]`, but better code would instead read a _line_ as a time with `fgets()` and then parse the line for the "words".

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works just fine, If you don't want regex complications in your code even though it's simple, use `strtok` after reading the whole string out. Then add it onto the array.

```
while(1){
    if(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) == EOF) break;
    printf("%s\n",word);
    const char s[2] = "-";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(word, s);
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", token );
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

Which gives the output

```
Alpha-Beta-Gamma-Delta-Epsilon

Alpha
Beta
Gamma
Delta
Epsilon

Zeta-Eta-Theta-Iota-Kappa-Lamda-Mi

Zeta
Eta
Theta
Iota
Kappa
Lamda
Mi

Ni-Ksi-Pi-Ro-Sigma

Ni
Ksi
Pi
Ro
Sigma
```

Cheers!

Comment: I don't see any answer containing regex

Comment: @FelixPalmen, what I meant by regex is the messy `%39[^-\n]` part, which is obviously confusing. You could just split the string upon a delimiter which is more simple

Comment: `%39[^-\n]` is not a regular expression, and is not at all confusing if you have read the documentation for the [`scanf()` family of functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2).